# MySql using Like to find the highest value of a string

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I don't think this should be all that complicated, but I'm having an issue building a query to pull the *higher* lower value from a table, where the identifier is higher.

So basically, I have a table that contains this (among other things):

```
8A     6253.85
8B     6184.64
```

I want to find the 8B and get the value of 6184.64.

I have used the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM payments WHERE contract = '".$contract."' AND payment LIKE '".$x."%' LIMIT 1
```

where $x is 8, but of course, get the 6253.85, because it comes first.

I tried:

```
SELECT * FROM payments WHERE contract = '".$contract."' AND payment LIKE '".$x."%' DESC LIMIT 1
```

which is essentially what I want to do, but this doesn't work (sql error).

If anyone can give me a quick suggestion on how to make sure I alway pull the "last" row that matches, I would appreciate it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: SQL tables are inherently unordered.  There is no "first" or "last" occurrence.  Do you have a column that you can use to define the ordering (for instance, a time stamp or auto-incremented id)?

Comment: So contract is 8A/8B?  What do you mean by the higher lower value?  Maybe it would be better to include more about your SQL structure.

Answer (score 2):

Just add an `ORDER BY payment DESC` (before the `LIMIT` clause).

```
 FROM ...
WHERE ...
  AND ...
ORDER BY payment DESC
LIMIT 1
```

(A LIKE predicate returns TRUE or FALSE (or NULL) for each row, and can't be used to sort higher and lower values, unless you have a special case of "known" values.)

Comment: After reading more into it, I'm assuming the OP has a column structure like '8A NUMBER' and he wants to order by the number.  I think the problem comes down to the way the table is structured.  The 8A and number should be separate.

Comment: @Devon: OP says he wants to find the `'8B'`, as opposed to the `'8A'`. Given the `payment LIKE '8%'` predicate, I'm assuming it's the payment column he wants to sort on.

Comment: Yes, I wanted the higher of the "payment number".  Since 8B is higher than 8A, I wanted the 8B.  Thank you for this answer, but I can't believe it was that simple...  I should have thought of that, and I should probably get more sleep.  :(